# JavaFX, tableview's data are not dysplaying

Tags: java, javafx

The problem is to display the data in the table (tableview)

The data is loaded. 2 lines and I can click on them in the table. But why they are not displayed I do not understand. 
thank you in advance

This is my controller class.

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import sample.model.Person;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Controller {

    public ObservableList<Person> observableList;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> name;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> surname;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> position;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> city;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> street;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, Integer> homenumber;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> birthday;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, Integer> salary;

    private Main mainApp;

    public void setMainApp(Main mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        // Добавление в таблицу данных из наблюдаемого списка
        table.setItems(getObservableList());
    }


    public void initTable(){

        observableList = getObservableList();
        table.setItems(observableList);

        name = new TableColumn<Person,String>("Имя");
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        surname = new TableColumn<Person,String>("Фамилия");
        surname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("surName"));
        position = new TableColumn<Person,String>("Должность");
        position.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("position"));
        city = new TableColumn<Person,String>("Город");
        city.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("city"));
        street = new TableColumn<Person,String>("Город");
        street.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("street"));
        homenumber = new TableColumn<Person,Integer>("Дом");
        homenumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("homeNumber"));
        birthday = new TableColumn<Person,String>("День рождения");
        birthday.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("birthday"));
        salary = new TableColumn<Person,Integer>("Зарплата");
        salary.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("salary"));

//        table.getColumns().setAll(name, surname, position, city, street, homenumber, birthday, salary);
    }

    public ObservableList<Person> getObservableList(){
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(new Person(1, "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", 6, "33", 7));
        people.add(new Person(2, "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", 6, "33", 7));
        ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(people);

        return data;
    }

}
```

and Main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {


    AnchorPane anchorPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("sample.fxml"));
        anchorPane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
//        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);


        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);



        primaryStage.show();
    }


    // ----- Метод получает данные из базы данных и выводит их в таблице
    // TODO хорошо бы когда-нибудь сделать получение из файла
    public void showPersonsOnTable(){
        // Получить данные

        // Распределить их в таблице
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Model Person

```
package sample.model;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {

    private IntegerProperty id;
    private StringProperty name;
    private StringProperty surName;
    private StringProperty position;
    private StringProperty city;
    private StringProperty street;
    private IntegerProperty homeNumber;
    private StringProperty birthday;
    private IntegerProperty salary;

    public Person(){}


    public Person(int id, String name, String surName, String position, String city, String street, int homeNumber,
                  String birthday, int salary) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.surName = new SimpleStringProperty(surName);
        this.position = new SimpleStringProperty(position);
        this.city = new SimpleStringProperty(city);
        this.street = new SimpleStringProperty(street);
        this.homeNumber = new SimpleIntegerProperty(homeNumber);
        this.birthday = new SimpleStringProperty(birthday);
        this.salary = new SimpleIntegerProperty(salary);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getSurName() {
        return surName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty surNameProperty() {
        return surName;
    }

    public void setSurName(String surName) {
        this.surName.set(surName);
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position.get();
    }

    public StringProperty positionProperty() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position.set(position);
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city.get();
    }

    public StringProperty cityProperty() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city.set(city);
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street.get();
    }

    public StringProperty streetProperty() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street.set(street);
    }

    public int getHomeNumber() {
        return homeNumber.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty homeNumberProperty() {
        return homeNumber;
    }

    public void setHomeNumber(int homeNumber) {
        this.homeNumber.set(homeNumber);
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday.get();
    }

    public StringProperty birthdayProperty() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday.set(birthday);
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty salaryProperty() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary.set(salary);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surName='" + surName + '\'' +
                ", position='" + position + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", street='" + street + '\'' +
                ", homeNumber=" + homeNumber +
                ", birthday=" + birthday +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                '}';
    }
}
```

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZfse.png)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421788/javafx-8-spinner-control-doesnt-update-value-thats-displayed) - not direct duplicate, but same issue. You are setting the value factories on columns which are never shown in the UI. Remove the creation of new `TableColumn` instances and use the ones created by `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: @sillyfly thank you very much.
I remove the creation of new Tableview in Controller.java
` private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>(); `
and changed in Main
` controller.setMainApp(this); ` to ` controller.initTable() `